# What is the best way to create struct-like object of C/C++ in python?

Tags: python, struct

I've been switching from Matlab to NumPy/Scipy, and I think NumPy is great in many aspects.

But one thing that I don't feel comfortable is that I cannot find a  data structure similar to `struct` in C/C++.

For example, I may want to do the following thing:

```
struct Parameters{
  double frame_size_sec;
  double frame_step_sec;
}
```

One simplest way is using a dictionary as follows.

```
  parameters = {"frame_size_sec" : 0.0, "frame_step_sec", 0.0}
```

But in case of a dictionary, unlike struct, any keys may be added. I'd like to restrict keys.

The other option might be using a class as follows. But it also has the same type of problems.

```
class Parameters:
  frame_size_sec = 0.0
  frame_step_sec = 0.0
```

From a thread, I saw that there is a data structure called named tuple, which looks great, but the biggest problem with it is that fields are immutable. So it is still different from what I want.

In sum, what would be the best way to use a struct-like object in python?

Answer (score 5):

If you don't need actual memory layout guarantees, user-defined classes can restrict their set of instance members to a fixed list using [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__slots__#object.__slots__). So for example:

```
class Parameters:  # On Python 2, class Parameters(object):, as __slots__ only applies to new-style classes
    __slots__ = 'frame_size_sec', 'frame_step_sec'
    def __init__(self, frame_size_sec=0., frame_step_sec=0.):
        self.frame_size_sec = float(frame_size_sec)
        self.frame_step_sec = float(frame_step_sec)
```

gets you a class where on initialization, it's guaranteed to assign two `float` members, and no one can add new instance attributes (accidentally or on purpose) to any instance of the class.

Please read the caveats at the `__slots__` documentation; in inheritance cases for instance, if a superclass doesn't define `__slots__`, then the subclass will still have `__dict__` and therefore can have arbitrary attributes defined on it.

If you need memory layout guarantees and stricter (C) types for variables, you'll want to look at [ctypes Structures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#structures-and-unions), but from what you're saying, it sounds like you're just trying to enforce a fixed, limited set of attributes, not specific types or memory layouts.

Comment: FYI, using `__slots__` does have some advantages. CPU-wise, it's basically irrelevant, but it reduces the per-instance memory cost significantly. On Python 3.4 (64 bit), for a 2 variable instance, the overhead of the object structure plus the structure for its `__dict__` is 152 bytes, vs. 56 bytes for the object structure (and no `__dict__`) if it's defined with `__slots__`. The difference on Python 2 is even more extreme (because Python 2 lacks shared-key dictionaries; the base object structure in both cases uses 64 bytes, but the `__dict__` required w/o `__slots__` takes it up to 344 bytes).

Answer (score 1):

While taking the risk of not being very Pythonic, you can create an immutable dictionary by subclassing the `dict` class and overwriting some of its methods:

```
def not_supported(*args, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError('ImmutableDict is immutable')


class ImmutableDict(dict):
    __delitem__ = not_supported
    __setattr__ = not_supported
    update = not_supported
    clear = not_supported
    pop = not_supported
    popitem = not_supported

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return self[item]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self.keys():
            dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError('ImmutableDict is immutable')
```

Some usage examples:

```
my_dict = ImmutableDict(a=1, b=2)
print my_dict['a']
>> 1
my_dict['a'] = 3 # will work, can modify existing key
my_dict['c'] = 1 # will raise an exception, can't add a new key
print my_dict.a # also works because we overwrote __getattr__ method
>> 3
```

Comment: That doesn't have a class wide limitation on the set of fields, it just limits you to defining the fields at instantiation time (and the OP explicitly said he didn't want immutable fields).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I've edited my answer to allow modifying existing keys but not allowing to add new keys, which is exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: Might want to have `__setattr__ = __setitem__` so `my_dict.a = 3` works without exposing the "it's really a dictionary, not an object" thing too obviously.